# Why does salted ice absorb more energy from the surroundings than ice when it has a lower melting point than ice?

Tags: thermodynamics

So how I think is that: salt lowers the melting point of ice. So lower melting point means less thermal energy required to melt. So if it requires less thermal energy to melt, it should mean that the amount of thermal energy absorbed from the surroundings is lower?(as I am assuming it only absorbs just the amount it needs to melt) If so, why does the salted ice, instead, pull a larger amount of energy from its surrounding?

Comment: Salted ice absorbs heat from your skin at a faster rates, because temperature difference between your body and salted ice melting point is greater. That's why salted ice feels colder.

Comment: "lower melting point means less thermal energy required to melt" I don't know whether it takes more or less energy to melt a given mass of ice, but the lower melting point means, that salty, melting ice is _colder_ than pure, melting H2O. (Agnius Valiliauskas said, "...feels colder." That's true. It _feels_ colder because it actually _is_ colder.)

Comment: Plus you're getting salt on the skin, but that's veering into Biology SE territory.

Comment: I think you're not saying everything that's on your mind because as written, it basically sounds like you're asking something similar to "*Why does a punch still hurt when it has less energy behind it than a bullet?*"

Comment: @DkNguyen Sorry I asked this without thinking. Should have phrased the question better. Can you tell me if the title is better?

Comment: @rainsoupreme Yes.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So lower melting point means less thermal energy required to melt.

No; we still need to provide essentially the same amount of latent heat to break the bonds associated with the solid state:

[image]

The lower melting point simply means that the liquid state has become more stable. The reason is that the liquid contains dissolved salt (and thus <100% water), but the ice doesn't (100% water), and so the water naturally moves to the area of lower water concentration. In the process, it's forced to melt, which draws energy from the surrounding regions.

In other words, we obtain cooling by forcing melting via a concentration difference.

> I know I went wrong somewhere as obviously the skin is damaged or hurt due to the salted ice pulling more heat/thermal energy(actually are they the same?) from the skin(pulling more heat than if the ice were not salted).

Yes; contact with salted ice is generally much more painful and damaging to tissue because the reasons above cause the salted ice to be colder—cold enough to freeze a large hunk of skin.